# get value from array passed in url

Tags: php

I am passing a array value in url

```
&settings=[{"ID":"1","visibility":"not_selected"},{"ID":"56","visibility":"not_selected"},{"ID":"57","visibility":"not_selected"}]
```

And getting it in php using `$settings=$_REQUEST['settings']` But using

```
                foreach(is_array($settings)  as $tag => $val) {

                    echo $combied_final[$tag]=$val;

                }
```

Does not seems to working in this case . I want ID and Visibility separate . How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

To access it as an array, make:

```
$settings=json_decode($_REQUEST['settings'], true);
```

and you better use $_GET, otherwise in $_REQUEST you will have also cookies.

Comment: @user1001176 "Didn't work", what do you mean? What did it return?

Comment: it works perfectly for me. Maybe you have some prepended file that adds slashes to $_REQUEST? then you must call `stripslashes` on `$_REQUEST['settings']`

Answer (score 0):

First use `json_decode` to decode the values:

```
$list = json_decode($_REQUEST['settings']);
foreach($list as $item) {
    print $item->ID . $item->visibility;
}
```